# pandas dataframe, with multi-index, to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to transform a pandas dataframe resulting from a groupby([columns]). The resulting index will have for each "target_index" different lists of words (example in image below). Transforming it with to_dict() seems to not be working directly (I have tried several orient arguments).

The Input dataframe:

[image]

The desired output (only two keys for the example):

```
{
"2060": {
    "NOUN": ["product"]
},
"3881": {
    "ADJ": ["greater", "direct", "raw"],
    "NOUN": ["manufacturing", "capital"],
    "VERB": ["increased"]
}
```

}

In order to recreate the below dataset:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([
        ["2060", "NOUN", ["product"]],
        ["2060", "ADJ", ["greater"]],
        ["3881", "NOUN", ["manufacturing", "capital"]],
        ["3881", "ADJ", ["greater", "direct", "raw"]],
        ["3881", "VERB", ["increased"]]
], columns= ["a", "b", "c"])
    
df= df.groupby(["a", "b"]).agg({"c": lambda x: x})
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could provide a cut-and-pastable bit of code to recreate your dataframe on our side.

Comment: My approach for something like this, possibly not the most efficient, but certainly doable, is to traverse the df one record at the time and construct the nested dict structure you want. You should be able to do it in less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: Hi joanis, for sure I'm adding an example. Regarding the solution you provided I think it would be unreasonably time consuming for large datasets. For sure there is a smarter way than nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input given in the constructor is different from the one in the image. I used the input in the constructor. You could use a lambda in groupby.apply to convert each group to dicts, then convert the aggregate to dict:

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.droplevel(0).to_dict()['c']).to_dict()
```

Another option is to use itertuples and dict.setdefault:

```
out = {}
for (ok, ik), v in df.itertuples():
    out.setdefault(ok, {}).setdefault(ik, []).extend(v)
```

Output:

```
{'2060': {'ADJ': ['greater'], 'NOUN': ['product']},
 '3881': {'ADJ': ['greater', 'direct', 'raw'],
  'NOUN': ['manufacturing', 'capital'],
  'VERB': ['increased']}}
```

Comment: Cool! First answer is great to avoid loops. In order to remove the column header it is needed "df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.droplevel(0)["c"].to_dict()).to_dict()" just for history. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nameless I think the `dict.setdefault` option is more efficient than the groupby method. But if your data is not hundreds of thousands of rows, the practical difference is probably not that big.

Comment: You are right. I have tested that for small dataset and it is faster. I think that first solution, like you said, will be preferable with very large datasets.